# How to get wordpress post permalink with all URL parameters?

Tags: wordpress, arguments, permalinks

the [get_permalink()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) function does not retrieve any URL parameter apparently.
Do you guys know a simple way to get the whole URL with a simple function ?
Thank you very much

Comment: can you give your url example?

Answer (score 0):

I actually find a solution myself, for anyone that would need it :

```
function getCompletePermalinkWithParams($new_parameters = array()) {
        $new_query_string = http_build_query(array_merge($_GET,$new_parameters));
        $complete_permalink_with_params = get_permalink () .'?'. $new_query_string;         
        return $complete_permalink_with_params;
    }
```

You can also use the function parameter to add new parameters to existing ones.
Cheers!